# SQLite to MariaDB conversion CONCAT with subquery and fixed strings

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

I need to convert some SQLite query to MariaDB.

I am having a problem with a request which looks like that (and works perfectly fine in SQLite):

```
SELECT Foo.id,
       Bar.name ||
       '_' ||
       (SELECT Toto.type
        FROM Toto, Titi
        WHERE Titi.id = 42
         AND Titi.id_Toto = Toto.id
       ) ||
       '/' ||
       Tutu.Name
FROM Foo,
     Bar,
     Tutu,
     Titi
WHERE Titi.id = 42
AND Foo.id_Bar = Bar.id
AND Bar.id_Tutu = Tutu.id
AND Tutu.id_Tutu = Titi.id
```

I modified it to be like that :

```
SELECT
    Foo.id,
    CONCAT( 
        Bar.name,
        '_',
        (SELECT Toto.type
         FROM Toto
           INNER JOIN Titi
             ON Titi.id_Toto = Toto.id
         WHERE Titi.id = 42
        ),
        '/',
        Tutu.Name
    )
FROM Foo
  INNER JOIN Bar
    ON Foo.id_Bar = Bar.id
  INNER JOIN Tutu
    ON Bar.id_Tutu = Tutu.id
  INNER JOIN Titi
    ON Tutu.id_Tutu = Titi.id
WHERE Titi.id = 42
```

I tried using the || for concatenation as well but in both cases I end up with the error

> Erreur SQL (1242) : Subquery returns more than 1 row

I read about GROUP_CONCAT but it takes only a request and no fixed strings

Is there any way to make this query work in MariaDB ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the current design, seems no need a correlated subquery, *which also filters out `Titi.id = 42` like the main query and possible to join with the other tables*, but JOINs among all tables needed such as

```
SELECT 
    Foo.id,
    CONCAT( 
        Bar.name,
        '_',Toto.type,'/',
        Tutu.Name
    )
 FROM Foo
 JOIN Bar
   ON Foo.id_Bar = Bar.id
 JOIN Tutu
   ON Bar.id_Tutu = Tutu.id
 JOIN Titi
   ON Tutu.id_Tutu = Titi.id
 JOIN Toto
   ON Titi.id_Toto = Toto.id    
WHERE Titi.id = 42
```